# Is it possible to "reset" any existing touches?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

```
Cocos2d-iphone 1.0.1.
```

- My main game scene requires the player to have a finger pressing the screen for the character to move.

  - **While** the character moves (thus the finger pressing the screen), a battle might occur. Such battle triggers a new `CCScene` which is **pushed** into the `CCDirector` (so the main game scene still exists within memory).
  - During the battle, naturally, the player will probably release his finger at some point.
  - When the battle is over, this `CCScene` is **popped**. Thus, the main game scene returns.
- Now here is a problem: the main game scene **still thinks that the finger that was initially pressing the screen before the battle is *still* pressing it at the same point, thus the joystick is still "functioning" and the player is still moving** despite the fact that the finger is no longer pressing the screen.

Is there a way to "reset" the screen touches? I'd like to do so in the `onEnter` method of the  main game scene. I tried something like

```
self.isTouchEnabled = NO;
self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
```

Hoping that such would re-register the touch dispatcher and thus causing some kind of reset. It did not work.

Basically, I need a way to tell the main game scene "dude, no one's touching the screen despite whatever you think".

**Edit**

Note that, if you press the screen again, it is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure I understand the problem:

After you pop the battle scene, the character continues moving around as if the user never released his finger from the joystick?

My initial thought is that you have a deeper underlying design flaw somewhere in the code. It is my understanding that you want to use at least one layer to handle input. Try shifting everything in that 'game' CCScene to a 'game' CCLayer and add the layer as a child of the scene. Then register the layer to receive touch input.

If that doesn't work, you could always use a flag. Compare the scene you are in to the scene you want to be in, and if not, don't activate the joystick controller. Kind of hack-y but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this kind of problem myself.

How i've fixed it:

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
for (UITouch *touch in touches){
[touchesOnScreen addObject:touch];
}
}

- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
for (UITouch *touch in touches){
[touchesOnScreen removeObject:touch];
}}

- (void)ccTouchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

[touchesOnScreen removeAllObjects];
}
```

So basically iOS keeps a pointer to every touch on the screen. What you do is manage those touches yourself with an NSSet. When you push the scene just set every UITouch from the set to nil. That is equivalent to `UITouchPhaseCancelled`. This will cancel all your touches on the screen. If the user still has his finger on the screen that touch wont be registered anymore...even if he moves it or something.

Note : you need to remove all objects in `ccTouchesCancelled` (it's called when the user has 6 or more touches on the screen) or else when he touches again the app crashes. If your app needs more than 5 touches you need to find a way around that.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the simplest solution is to have your CCDirector, on completion of popping your battle scene, call first `resignFirstResponder` then 'becomeFirstResponder` on the offending view; off the top of my head anyway it seems that ought to forward on the touches to another responder, hopefully letting it fizzle out when no one else handles it.

A more complicated dive into the UIView methods provides this private call `cancelTouchTracking`. Most likely it does something similar to what @skytz has put together. ***Warning: That last will mostly likely get you rejected in the app store process, but for your info there it is.***

I'd opt for the simpler solution and hope it works. O_o